# DNA vs Family Tree

Tags: dna

I recently got a DNA match for my wife and it was suggested that this man is a 1st cousin once removed or 2nd cousin.  When I pursued that branch of the tree to confirm the match, it seems they are actually 3rd cousins.  With a 3.6% match and 252 cM, is there a way to know which one is more likely?  Or is this just one of those things where the estimate of relationship is nothing more than a guess?

Comment: [DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/252) is your friend here.  It gives you a list of possible relationships and probabilities. Some of them, I suspect, you will be able to rule out immediately (great-great-uncle, for example)

Answer (score -1):

You are correct it is just an estimate based on the mathematical range of the cM's that they are using to identify a cousin. For example on one website a third cousin is 0-217 cM but on another company chart a third cousin is 0-109 cM.